# Can't install Team Viewer on 13.10

Tags: installation, 13.10, teamviewer

I just fresh installed 13.10, but now the teamviewer.deb file won't install `due to an unresolvable dependency: lib32asound2`. I found a download link [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/lib32asound2/1.0.25-4ubuntu4) but also this package won't install `due to an unresolvable dependency: libasound2 (= 1.0.25-4ubuntu4)`

and help ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to try gdebi package installer for install it.You can install it from [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/)

Comment: it's giving me a message `Dependency is not satisfiable : libsound2 (=1.0.25-4ubuntu4)` and i have the `libsound2 1.0.27-4ubuntu7`